# How can I label a categorical variable based on the size of each category?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I have the results of a cluster analysis which tells me in which cluster a certain observation is. My true data is almost the same but the label of each cluster is different. Say the data looks like this:

```
S=sample(c(1,2,3),size = 200,prob = c(0.2,0.3,0.5),replace = TRUE)
dt_estimate=as.data.frame(cbind(Obs = c(1:200),S))
dt_true=dt_estimate%>% mutate(S=case_when(
  S=='1'~3,
  S=='2'~1,
  S=='3'~2))
```

I need to relabel the clusters for one of the datasets so that the labels refer to the same cluster. I mean cluster1 in the estimate results is actually referring to cluster1 of my true data.
I can not correct the label manually since I have more than 1000 cluster results.
How can I solve this?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it? Maybe show a small example with 10 rows and show corresponding expected output for it?

Comment: Please be more specific and maybe you can show us the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
change_size_label <- function(df_ori){
  # create a table to count the frequencies
  freq_count <- data.frame(table(df_ori$state))
  freq_count <-freq_count[order(freq_count$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
  ranking <- freq_count[1]
  
  for(ind in 1:nrow(df_ori)){
    state = as.integer(df_ori[ind,'state'])
    if (state == as.integer(ranking[1,1])) {
      new_state = 1
    } else if (state == as.integer(ranking[2,1])) {
      new_state = 2
    } else {
      new_state = 3
    }
    df_ori[ind,'new_state'] = new_state
  }
  return(df_ori)
}
```

the code to relabel is sth as above.

Comment: In R you’d normally pull the assignment out of the `if`. That is, you’d write, instead of the above, `df_ori[ind, 'new_state'] = if (state == as.integer(ranking[1, 1])) 1 else if (state == as.integer(ranking[2, 1)) 2 else 3`. But since this is happening inside a loop I’d almost certainly remove the whole loop and use `match` instead.

Comment: Thanks！！！！ I will check the match function as suggested